# Как передать textarea в php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Пытаюсь настроить отправку сообщенй с формы на e-mail.Уже все сделал

```js
<?
$to = 'tooboos123@gmail.com,2boos@ukr.net'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
$subject = 'Сообщение с сайта'; //Загаловок сообщения
$message =
  '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.
'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Имя: '.$_GET['name'].
'</p>
                        <p>E-mail: '.$_GET['email'].
'</p>
                        <p>Сообщение: '.$_GET['massage'].
'</p> 
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
$headers. = "From: 2boos@ukr.net"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
?>
```

```html
<form action="send.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail">
  <textarea type="text" name="massage" id="massage-field" placeholder="Massage" rows="8"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAND MASSAGE">
</form>
```

Данный из input отправляются, а из textarea нет.Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Может, текст не влазит? Попробуйте `post` вместо `get`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
<?
$to = 'tooboos123@gmail.com,2boos@ukr.net'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
$subject = 'Сообщение с сайта'; //Загаловок сообщения
$message =
  '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.
'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Имя: '.$_GET['name'].
'</p>
                        <p>E-mail: '.$_GET['email'].
'</p>
                        <p>Сообщение: '.$_GET['massage'].
'</p> 
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
$headers. = "From: 2boos@ukr.net"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
?>
```

```html
<form action="send.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail">
  <textarea type="text" name="massage" id="massage-field" placeholder="Massage" rows="8"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAND MASSAGE">
</form>
```

просто перезапустил openserver заработало.Не знаю в чем причина была